# Problem using Beaglebone Black UART with C-Program

Tags: c, uart, beagleboneblack

Stack Overflow,

I desperately need help getting a BeagleBone Black UART to work from a C program.
The code that I am attempting to use is listed below. The code came from Chapter 8 of Derek Molloy’s “Beaglebone” book.

The code compiles without any warnings or errors and seems to run. The program passes the sanity checks that are built into the C code below. The program finishes by printing “Finished sending the message, exiting.” to the console.

The fundamental reason that I think the UART4 is not sending data is that I see no activity on P9/13 when monitoring with a nice digital O’scope. I have also tried monitoring the port by way of a PC running a terminal program.

I am convinced the C-program is reading my command-line message (e.g. “testing123”) correctly. I modified to code to print the message to the console and it printed the message as expected. I also modified the code run in a loop to make it easier to monitor P9/13 with the O’scope. The O’scope shows a constant 3.3VDC on the P9/13.

I also blindly tried a pull-down resistor. The port does not provide much current. A 2k Ohm resistor loaded the port to about 0.2 Volts.

I verified that ttyO4 and ttyS4 are in /DEV, whatever that means.

I am not certain what version of Debian that I am using. I monitored the “header” output from J1 and found this:
Debian GNU/Linux 9 ebb ttyS0
BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2019-08-03

Also, I found this:
Machine ID: 229f313330aab6c19873bdc15d4645c7
Boot ID: b74381516ae64aefa37415709164f0e4
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Kernel: Linux 4.14.108-ti-r113
Architecture: arm

Do I need to enable the UART port or pins? If so, how do I do this and how do I confirm it was successfully done?  Do I need to hardwire the control lines (e.g. CTS, RTS)?  Do I need to edit the uEnv.txt file?

I am almost certain my board is a rev-c.

As a final note, I tried a similar C-code from the “Bad to the Bone” book with similar unfavorable results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Norm

```
/* Simple send message example for communicating with the
*  UART that is connected to a desktop PC.  */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<termios.h>
#incl`ude<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int file, count;
   if(argc!=2){
       printf("Please pass a message string to send, exiting!\n");
       return -2;
   }
   if ((file = open("/dev/ttyO4", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY))<0){
      perror("UART: Failed to open the device.\n");
      return -1;
   }
   struct termios options;
   tcgetattr(file, &options);
   options.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;
   options.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
   tcflush(file, TCIFLUSH);
   tcsetattr(file, TCSANOW, &options);

   // send the string plus the null character
   if ((count = write(file, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])+1))<0){
      perror("UART: Failed to write to the output.\n");
      return -1;
   }
   close(file);
   printf("Finished sending the message, exiting.\n");
   return 0;
```

Comment: Do you see any TX pin activity when `echo "test" > /dev/ttyO4`? Did you try to configure and write to the port with another program, e.g. `picocom`? What `stty < /dev/ttyO4` says?

Comment: I'm confused to what your setup is. Are you running this on the BB board, or are you running this on you PC? How are you connected to the BB board? USB? "*output from J1 and found this: Debian GNU/Linux 9 ebb ttyS0 BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2019-08-03*" is read from where? (a serial connection from you PC?) Debian Stretch is fine. `/dev/tty04` is from the BB or PC. Sorry for the questions. Have done this with lots of TI boards, but not a BB specifically.

Comment: The code you're using is low-quality, and does not conform to best practices. See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html). You're using the Linux OS rather than baremetal, so the program accesses a serial terminal rather than the UART directly. Rather than be "*uncertain*", learn to use OS resources to obtain the kernel version, if the driver has been installed for the UART, and if pinctrl has multiplexed the pins for the UART. Use the boot log, the **/proc/tty** files, and the **pinctrl** files in the **debugfs** filesystem.

Comment: Dimich, I greatly appreciate your helpful input. I was unaware of the echo command until I read your note. It helped remove uncertainty from the problem

Comment: David, No problem with the questions. I appreciate your input. I was running the C-program on the Beaglebone Black. I connected my PC to the Beagle with USB and ran SSH with Putty terminal program. The  "output from J1 and found this: Debian GNU/Linux 9 ebb ttyS0 BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2019-08-03" was read from Beaglebone connector J1 using a TTL to usb converter connected to my PC running Realterm. The problem turned out to be the uart output pin was defined as "input" as opposed to "uart".

Comment: Sawdust, Thanks for your input. I read Setting Terminal Modes Properly and definitely benefitted from the effort.

Comment: Have you performed a post mortem to clearly understand what the problem was? Seems like you need to learn about SoC pin multiplexing and the Linux kernel **pinctrl**. Too bad you solved this problem by shooting-in-the-dark with just various possible quick fixes, instead of learning proper debugging techniques. Instead of a HW perspective (e.g. "*output from J1*"), suggest you learn the functionality you're accessing (J1 is the serial console that displays kernel messages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your image and kernel...

1. Try /dev/ttyS4
2. Or try /dev/bone/uart/4

Also...I am pretty sure config-pin was available in kernel 4.14.x even though that kernel is EOL from their org.

If you come across /dev/ttyS4 not working, try config-pin for your specific pins used...

Comment: De Funct, I used your advice and had success. More specifically, I used config-pin to set P9/13 to "uart" as opposed to its default of "in". The C-program that I posted here then worked just fine. Do you know how to perform this task (setting pin mode) within the C-program? This is my first time using stackoverflow, so I am not familiar with the protocol. It says to avoid using words like "thanks".  So. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: No, I currently do not have any input on using config-pin in source. Maybe calling the location of what the .dts file(s) state can provide support. For instance...

Answer (score -1):

```
 ////////////////////////////////////////
 // blinkLED.c
 // Blinks the P9_14 pin based on the P9_18 pin
 // Wiring:
 // Setup:
 // See:
 ////////////////////////////////////////
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXSTR 100

int main() {
  FILE *fpbutton, *fpLED;
  char LED[] = "50";   // Look up P9.14 using gpioinfo | grep -e chip -e P9.14
  char button[] = "7"; // Look up P9.42 using gpioinfo | grep -e chip -e P9.18
  char GPIOPATH[] = "/sys/class/gpio";
  char path[MAXSTR] = "";

  // Make sure LED is exported
  snprintf(path, MAXSTR, "%s%s%s", GPIOPATH, "/gpio", LED);
  if (!access(path, F_OK) == 0) {
    snprintf(path, MAXSTR, "%s%s", GPIOPATH, "/export");
    fpLED = fopen(path, "w");
    fprintf(fpLED, "%s", LED);
    fclose(fpLED);
  }
 
  // Make it an output LED
  snprintf(path, MAXSTR, "%s%s%s%s", GPIOPATH, "/gpio", LED, "/direction");
  fpLED = fopen(path, "w");
  fprintf(fpLED, "out");
  fclose(fpLED);

  // Make sure bbuttonutton is exported
  snprintf(path, MAXSTR, "%s%s%s", GPIOPATH, "/gpio", button);
  if (!access(path, F_OK) == 0) {
    snprintf(path, MAXSTR, "%s%s", GPIOPATH, "/export");
    fpbutton = fopen(path, "w");
    fprintf(fpbutton, "%s", button);
    fclose(fpbutton);
  }
 
  // Make it an input button
  snprintf(path, MAXSTR, "%s%s%s%s", GPIOPATH, "/gpio", button, "/direction");
  fpbutton = fopen(path, "w");
  fprintf(fpbutton, "in");
  fclose(fpbutton);

  // I don't know why I can open the LED outside the loop and use fseek before
  //  each read, but I can't do the same for the button.  It appears it needs
  //  to be opened every time.
  snprintf(path, MAXSTR, "%s%s%s%s", GPIOPATH, "/gpio", LED,    "/value");
  fpLED    = fopen(path, "w");
  
  char state = '0';

  while (1) {
    snprintf(path, MAXSTR, "%s%s%s%s", GPIOPATH, "/gpio", button, "/value");
    fpbutton = fopen(path, "r");
    fseek(fpLED, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(fpbutton, "%c", &state);
    printf("state: %c\n", state);
    fprintf(fpLED, "%c", state);
    fclose(fpbutton);
    usleep(250000);   // sleep time in microseconds
  }
}
```

This is older source that may or may not work depending on your kernel/image and date in time of said kernel.

Also...

line 15 and line 16 show `gpioinfo` as a command. On the BBB, one can find many pins that are available and in what format which is usually `default`.

Calling config-pin during the source may help or you can have it preset w/ a .dtbo file in `/boot/uEnv.txt`. Overlays are, was, and still are a thing w/ the am335x on the BBB.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/driver-api/pinctl.html may help a bit for research purposes. Config-pin types can be called during source but since kernels and time changes, it will be hard to help completely as I may never get the exact kernel and image you have currently.